# Why doesn't my last element print?

Tags: java, printwriter

I'm on the last steps of finishing my BST and Trie in java and I've come across this problem. I can't print the last element out to a file. It's not the toString methods cause I've tried switching them around. I remember a while back one of my professors mentioned something about closing the file. Something along the lines of putting an int value inside the parentheses of the close method, I'll develop on this below (not sure if I'm right thought, just something I vaguely recall)
Here's a snippet of the code that I'm having trouble with.

```
       try{
           output = new PrintWriter(inputFile);

           output.println("BST:");
           output.println(tree.toString());
           output.println("Trie:");
           output.println(trie.myToString());


           output.close();

        }
           catch(IOException e){}
        System.out.println("Goodbye");
```

so if I recall correctly, the teacher said to do something like output.close(0) or the like, but it's shooting me errors. Can anyone help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: Ideally you would put a `finally{ if (output != null){output.flush();output.close();}` right after the closing brace of your last catch block. This will make sure that you release the file. That being said, you need to provide more information regarding the fact that your last element is not printing.

Comment: As npinti says you'll need more detail and yes finally is the way to close things.

Comment: Sorry guys, if I didn't word my statement correctly. 
By last element I meant I meant that the last printLn that I'm calling will print onto the screen but not into my file, in case I was mixing you guys up with that.

Comment: You mean this: `System.out.println("Goodbye");`?

Comment: um what. so you're saying System.out.println() is printing to screen instead of file? Why do you expect it to print to a file? System.out typically *is* the screen. If you want to print to a file, you should to output.println().

Comment: No, sorry for all the confusion. 
it'll print "BST:"
it'll print tree.toString()
it'll print "Trie:" 
but it won't print trie.myToString()

It'll print it to the screen but not the txt file

Comment: @eis No, I know exactly what System.out does. refer to the comment I just made

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
catch(IOException e){}
```

you are swallowing the reason here. Don't do that.

At least print the reason with

```
catch(IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace(System.err);
}
```

Comment: I'm still not done with it. I was going to include all that before turning it in. 
Thank you though I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
output.flush()
```

before close the output

or try

```
  output = new PrintWriter(inputFile,true);
```

Comment: Close should call flush - that won't be the problem.

Comment: or try output = new PrintWriter(inputFile,true);

Comment: output  = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(inputFile));

Comment: are you sure trie.myToString() is return a value . Print is on top of the method and see you get something

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this. What happens if you replace output.println(trie.myToString()); with output.println("hello"); ?